# User setting for default save and open locations in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting that can be added to the settings.json for the default open/save location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. The workaround would be to create a shortcut to launch vscode with the location of the folder you want to open on startup. You can append a path as argument for VS Code to open.

In addition, VS Code will always remember the last folder you opened and restore it when you restart.

Comment: This answer is old. See @starball's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code 1.80, I think you can use the `files.dialog.defaultPath` setting. Caveat from [the release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_default-file-dialog-location):

> This default is used only as a fallback when no other location is known, for example in empty VS Code windows.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Edit the shortcut of VSCode and change the startup location.
On Windows:

1. Open Start Menu and locate Visual Studio Code
2. Right click on the Visual Studio Code icon
3. Select More >
4. Select Open File Location
5. Right click on the shortcut icon and select Property
6. Change the Startup Location to what you want

Answer (score -1):

Save files to a default location in local machine with VS Code on Mac:
[image: Save files to a default location in local machine with VS Code on Mac]

Comment: How did you get that screen?  I only know how to get to settings via the jason.

Comment: Again, VS Code - VS Community is a different product.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming and I thought it was the same product. LOL

Answer (score -2):

[image: Picture of how to access preferences]

Here is a screenshot of how to get into VS preferences. Click VS community (on your menu bar) and the drop-down menu will display preferences. Within preferences, click on projects then load/save and you will find the default load/save locations.

Comment: Ahh the question is on VS Code not Visual Studio